# How reliable is triggering a aws lambda function using cloudwatch events from a mongodb trigger than a message in sqs?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

I want to invoke a AWS lambda function when a new document is created in mongodb atlas. I found an option the we can integrate mongodb atlas as a trigger to lambda function.
But is it reliable to do that?
Is there a chance of missing a trigger?
Should I use an SQS queue and push a message to SQS whenever a new document is created?

Thanks in advance.